# Finding the number of fractions with unique values where the range for the denominator and numerator is in $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$

Tags: fractions

Imagine that you have a fraction, where both the numerator and denominator take values in the set $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$. Let us assume that the fraction is smaller then and or eqal to 1. The question is how many unique values can you get with every single combination in relation to $n$ and is there a function to describe it?

So far, I think that there  is a relation to prime numbers but I do not know what it is.
Here are the values for $n = 1,2,\dots,20$:
\begin{align*}
& 1=1,
2=\mathbf{2},
3=\mathbf{5},
4=\mathbf{7},
5=\mathbf{11},
6=\mathbf{13},
7=\mathbf{19}, \\
& 8=\mathbf{23},
9=\mathbf{29},
10=33,
11=\mathbf{43},
12=\mathbf{47},
13=\mathbf{59},
14=65, \\
& 15=\mathbf{73}, 16=81, 17=\mathbf{97}, 18=\mathbf{103}, 19=121, 20=129,
\end{align*} where the emphasized numbers are primes.

Comment: look up Farey sequences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence

Comment: I think your values are off by two - for example for $n = 3$ you should have $1/2, 1/3, 2/3$ (so $f(n) = 3$) and for $n = 4$ you should have in addition to these $1/6, 5/6$, so $f(n) = 5$.  That said, take a look at https://oeis.org/A002088 .

Comment: @MichaelLugo For $n =3$, you are missing $1/1$. So $f(3) = 4, f(4) = 6, f(5) = 10$ like in your OEIS link.

Comment: @CalvinLin I thought about that but the OP said "let us assume that the fraction is smaller than 1".

Comment: @MichaelLugo True, the phrase "smaller than" is often ambiguous. Though then $f(1) = 0 , f(2) = 1$, so OP can decide how they want to fix the sequence.